# downloading a community website on own server

Tags: web-hosting, web-development

I have a mobile community website on wapka and now I wish to set up own server. But wapka have no options regarding this. How can I download whole website, users, pictures with same features on my server?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to ask people who know about wapka - try this link https://www.facebook.com/WapkaOfficial/